# Vaadin 7 - try to add a popup to archetype-application-example in css

Tags: java, css, popup, vaadin

Good evening,
I try to work with Vaadin 7. I work with the CRUD-example: 
https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example

The layout of the ProductForm ist defined by a file called  ProductFormDesign.html . I try to ad a button in combination with a popup. So when I press Button A, I want to show a popup with the Text "Hi". Can anybody give me a hint? Here is the document for the implementation of the popup in Vaadin https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-popupview.html. Here is the  ProductFormDesign.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="package-mapping" content="x:org.vaadin.mockapp.samples.crud"     />
</head>
<body>
<v-css-layout id="product-form" style-name="product-form-wrapper">
<v-vertical-layout height-full spacing style-name="form-layout">
    <v-text-field caption="Product name" _id="productName" width-full />
    <v-horizontal-layout width-full spacing>
        <v-text-field caption="Price" _id="price" width-full />
        <x-number-field _id="stockCount" caption="In Stock" width-full />
        </v-horizontal-layout>
        <v-combo-box caption="Availability" _id="availability" width-full null-selection-allowed=false text-input-allowed=false />
        <x-category-field _id="category" caption="Categories" width-full />
        <v-css-layout :expand style-name="expander" />
        <v-button style-name="primary" _id="save">Save</v-button>
        <v-button style-name="cancel" _id="cancel" click-shortcut="escape">Cancel</v-button>
        <v-button style-name="danger" _id="delete">Delete</v-button>
    </v-vertical-layout>
</v-css-layout>
</body>
</html>
```

I now how to ad a button and a textfield. But I do not understand how to implement a popup with the help of the documentation of Vaadin. I already spent 7 hours with this topic and I have no clue. Also google did not give my an answer or help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you building a Java application, or a html application? For a html application you will need to use the vaadin elements of vaadin 8. https://vaadin.com/elements/get-started

Comment: It's a Java webapplication. Most of it is written in Java. But one part of the layout is driven by the HTML-file I provided in my first post. There I can just add " <v-button style-name="danger" _id="anotherButton">anotherButton</v-button>" and add to the ProductFormDesign.java     "protected Button anotherButton;" https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example/blob/master/mockapp-ui/src/main/java/org/vaadin/mockapp/samples/crud/ProductFormDesign.java    And I try to add a popup instead of a new button but have no clue how.